# Symfony Delete image uploaded with filesystem

Tags: image, symfony, upload, filesystems

i would like to delete an image from my / uploads folder with fileSystem but I can't do it. Here is my code.
Thank you so much !

```
/**
 * Permet de supprimer des images
 *
 * @Route("/delete/image/{id}", name="image_delete", methods={"DELETE"})
 *
 * @param Image $image
 * @param EntityManagerInterface $manager
 * @return Response
 */
public function deleteImage(Image $image, EntityManagerInterface $manager)
{
    /**
     * Je gère la suppression du dossier "uploads" ou l'image est stockée
     */
    //Je récupère le nom de l'image
    $filename = $image->getName();
    // Je crée une instance de kla classe fileSystem
    $fileSystem = new Filesystem();
    //Je supprime l'image du dossier
    $fileSystem->remove('%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/'.$filename);

    /**
     * Je gère la suppression en bdd
     */
    $manager->remove($image);
    $manager->flush();
    return new Response('deleted', Response::HTTP_OK);



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the path you are passing throw the method:

```
$fileSystem->remove('%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/'.$filename);
```

`%kernel.project_dir%` does not work at this position, because the `Filesystem` class does not have access to the kernel configuration. You have to get it first like this:

```
$projectDir = $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir');
$fileSystem->remove($projectDir.'/public/uploads/'.$filename);
```